# SSRS 2005 Sort Matrix by column name values

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Group,
I have a SSRS report I am creating which is based off of a cube, and it generats (in a sense) three columns dynamically.  Basically it has [Last Yeah Current Month Qty Sold], [This Year Current Month Qty Sold], and then [Variance] (Chart 1).  What I want to do is sort the "Product" Group based on the variance column descending (Chart 2).  It is initially sorted by [Product Group #].

(Chart 1)

[image]

(Chart 2)

[image]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I generated an example dataset (just through a query) to test this but the principle should be the same.

You need to apply a sorting expression to the Matrix row group that only takes total *Variance* into consideration and ignores the other columns.

You can use expression similar to the following:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!col.Value = "Variance", Fields!val.Value, 0))
```

You can see this only counts *Variance* values as required.

Apply this to the row group sorting expression:

[image]

Click **Edit** then **Sorting** then add the sort expression.

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Sorted by *Variance* as required.

Comment: Ian, thanks for the response. That makes all the sense in the world... It looks like it works, but for some reason isn't for me.  This is kind of a complex matrix, so there must be something else with my formatting that is creating an issue.  I'll have to keep digging.